# Error while loading power query - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: excel, powerquery

For some of the users they're not able to refresh the query. I can't even enter into the query editor on their computers, while for me and other users it's working perfectly fine. What could be the solution to this?

It throws the following error:

```
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Not enough memory resources are available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)

Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Evaluation.EvaluatorHost.CreateSession(PackageEditorContext context, PackageReference packageReference, EvaluationSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Analysis.AnalysisManager.StartPackageAnalysis(AnalysisSession session, PackageReference packageReference, Int32 editVersion, Boolean refreshData, HashSet`1 formulaFilter, String[] defaultOptionalModules, Action callback)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Analysis.AnalysisManager.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<StartSessionAnalysisCore>b__0(Object state)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.GlobalizedThreadPool.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<WrapCallback>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)

Stack Trace Message:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Not enough memory resources are available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)

Invocation Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Windows.UIHost.RaiseErrorDialog(IWindowHandle activeWindow, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, LocalizedString dialogTitle, LocalizedString dialogMessage, Boolean useGDICapture)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Native.NativeUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<SendAndMarshalExceptions>b__0(Object null)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


Supports Premium Content:
TRUE
```

Comment: The error says `not enough memory`.Have you tried `VeriPaq` in `DAX SAtudio` ? maybe something is making the model large.

Comment: i'm doing it in excel, how could it help?